# Fetch all columns from a Parse database which contain a common word

Tags: android, parse-platform

How can I fetch all columns from Parse against an object ID? In my case all the episodes are saved in different columns of a database. I want to fetch all episodes of a novel using `objectId`.

All columns names of different episodes are named `episode1`, `episode2` and so on. I can't understand how to fetch all the columns which contain the word `episode` using `objectId`.

[image: Table screenshot, two rows, colums object ID, several columns starting with episode followed by a number]

Comment: Is it too late to change the database schema?

Comment: yes dude because same database is using on ios app

Comment: Is there a problem with just including all columns (which queries do by default)?  If you don't have any columns with huge data in them you can just do that.  If that is not an option then there is a fairly clean way to do what you want, as long as you know how many episode columns there will be.  If you don't know that then it still may be possible but I'm not sure.